# Hash table where statement

Tags: sas, hashtable

I'm trying to use the hash object as something like an sql query.

What I wanted to know is the equivalent of a conditional if statement for SAS hash objects.

I want a conditional statement on my second hash object that filters based on effective_date.

Something like

```
If effective_date<"27.05.1966"'d then output.
```

rc=h.find() returns a 0/1 depending if found or not found but how do I add if statements or where statements to the hash objects?

I was thinking something like

```
if rc=0 and effective_date<"27.05.1966"'d then do;
set want;
hoh.add();
output;
end;
```

But I don't think the hash table would know that effective_date is being referenced this way.

Original proc sql statement I'm trying to translate:

```
proc sql;
    create table tb2 as
        select distinct
            a.effective_date,
            a.S_FACILITY_CUSTOMER_ID as customer_id,
            a.s_facility_id as facility_id,
            a.s_facility_type as facility_type,
            a.CUSTOMER_ASSET_CLASS_ID,
            a.FACILITY_START_DATE,
            a.FACILITY_end_DATE,
            sum
            (
        case 
            when midas_type_id in ("KC", "KR", "KO","KF") then sum(a.loan_prinicpal_local,a.loan_interest_unpaid_local)
            else 0 
        end
                )
            as arrear_amount,

sum(a.LOAN_PRINICPAL_LOCAL) as amount_local
            from tbexport.tb_export_full_all a
                where a.effective_date between "&repdate_from"dt and "&repdate_to"dt

                    AND BUSINESS_SEGMENT NOT IN ("MCR", "SE", "COR")
                group by s_facility_id, effective_date;
quit;
```

This is what I come up with:

```
data _NULL_;

if 0 then set tbexport.tb_export_full_all;

   dcl hash HoH(ordered : 'D');                                                    
   HoH.definekey('s_facility_id','effective_date');
   HoH.definedata('effective_date', 'S_FACILITY_CUSTOMER_ID', 's_facility_type','s_facility_id','CUSTOMER_ASSET_CLASS_ID',
'FACILITY_START_DATE','FACILITY_end_DATE','midas_type_id','BUSINESS_SEGMENT','loan_prinicpal_local','loan_interest_unpaid_local');
   HoH.definedone();
   dcl hiter HoHiter('HoH');

  do until (lr);
      set tbexport.tb_export_full_all end=lr;
        where '&repdate_from.'dt<=effective_date<='&repdate_to.'dt;
        if HoH.find() ne 0 then do;  
 
         dcl hash h(multidata : 'Y', ordered : 'D');
         h.definekey('effective_date','s_facility_id');
         h.definedata('effective_date', 'S_FACILITY_CUSTOMER_ID', 's_facility_type','s_facility_id','CUSTOMER_ASSET_CLASS_ID',
'FACILITY_START_DATE','FACILITY_end_DATE','midas_type_id','BUSINESS_SEGMENT','loan_prinicpal_local','loan_interest_unpaid_local');
         h.definedone();
         dcl hiter hi('h');
         HoH.add();

        end;    
      h.add();
   end;

   do until(HoHiter.next() = 1);  
        set tbexport.tb_export_full_all; 
        if hoh.find()=0 and midas_type_id in ("KC" , "KR" , "KO" , "KF") then do;    
        arrear_amount= sum(loan_prinicpal_local,loan_interest_unpaid_local);
        end;
      hoh.output(dataset:'tb2',ordered:'A');
   end;

run;
```

But it gives me this error:

ERROR:  An exception has been encountered.
Please contact technical support and provide them with the following traceback information:

The SAS task name is [DATASTEP]
Segmentation Violation

Comment: When you test a variable you are testing its current value. So you probably want to test after the SET statement otherwise what value are you testing? If the find() is successful then the variables defined by the DEFINEDATA() method will be updated with the values retrieved from the hash object, so you can test the values.  But you are not using valid syntax for date literals in your posted code.  You have unbalanced quotes and the string in the quotes is not something the DATE informat can translate.

Comment: Please explain what you are are trying to code.  "sql query" is too generic and does not explain what type of query you are trying to replicate.

Comment: @Tom Simple subseting from larger DB table based on date and a sum if conditions are met. I will add the exact proc sql statement to my post.

Comment: @Tom <You have unbalanced quotes and the string in the quotes is not something the DATE informat can translate.> So is 'something' preferred over "something" ?

Comment: A date literal is a quoted string with the letter d after the close quote.  The value in the quotes needs to be a string that the DATE informat can convert into a date.  Example: `"01JAN1960"d`

Comment: Your SQL is including variables that are neither grouping variables nor aggregate functions.  PROC SQL will perform a re-merge to attach to aggregate values to those detailed observations.  You might want to look into using a double DOW loop in a data step to replicate that remerge.  Of if you cannot access the data sorted then you will need to process the file twice, first to generate the aggregate sums and then again to generate the detailed output observations.

Comment: I don't think you need a hash of hashes here - this should be doable directly in a single hash table.

Comment: Are you running out of memory for the HASH object(s)?  How many distinct combinations of  s_facility_id and effective_date are there?

Comment: @Tom 10s of million per year and yes I often run out of memory on bigger tables thus the HoH approach .@Joe I wanted to start learning about how to use HoH and hashesh in general starting from simple tasks.

Comment: 10's of millions might fit into memory.  But 10's of millions times 365 days per year times multiple years probably not so much.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable without a hash of hashes.  This roughly replicates what you're doing - creating a summary by several variables.  The logic is pretty straightforward to add to it at this point I think - it can be a `where` statement, probably.  Just make sure to add it to both of the dataset reads (probably best as a `where` data set option, perhaps?).

```
data want;
  if 0 then set sashelp.prdsale;
  
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    declare hash h();
    h.defineKey('country','region');
    h.defineData('actual_sum','predict_sum');
    h.defineDone();    
      do _n_ = 1 to prdsale_recs;
        set sashelp.prdsale nobs=prdsale_recs point=_n_;
        rc = h.find();
        actual_sum = sum(actual_sum,actual);
        predict_sum = sum(predict_sum,predict);
        rc = h.replace();       
      end;
  end;  
  set sashelp.prdsale;

  rc = h.find();
run;
```

Comment: I was really hoping to learn how to use HoH with this example but your approach is entirely valid. I don't really see how it selects distinct combinations though.

Comment: the table is also unsorted btw, so I think I actually do need HoH.

Comment: Do you mean your input table?

Comment: Yes I do mean the input table.

Comment: Sorting doesn’t matter. Why do you think you want HoH?

Comment: @joe To reduce used RAM and to select distinct.

Comment: Why do you think HoH is needed for either of those purposes?